# INSERT Stored Procedure works but data is not inserted when called from method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert data into my table. I have created a stored procedure that will do this. I also created a method that calls the stored procedure. When I click on the submit button, the click event is fired and I get the input data and call the method to insert to the table.

I get no errors but when I check in my database, the data has not been inserted.

I have tried executing the stored procedure manually and it does work.

Here's my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].AddRestaurant
    @theName VARCHAR(250),
    @theAddr VARCHAR(350), 
    @theCity VARCHAR(50),
    @theState VARCHAR(2),
    @theZip VARCHAR(5),
    @theCategory INT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Restaurants (RestName, RestAddr, RestCity, RestState, RestZip, CategoryID)
    VALUES (@theName, @theAddr, @theCity, @theState, @theZip, @theCategory)
END
```

Here's my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Restaurants] 
(
    [RestaurantID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [RestName]     VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    [RestAddr]     VARCHAR(350) NULL,
    [RestCity]     VARCHAR(50)  NULL,
    [RestState]    VARCHAR(2)   NULL,
    [RestZip]      VARCHAR(5)   NULL,
    [CategoryID]   INT          NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RestaurantID] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Restaurants_CatergoryID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryID]) 
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Categories] ([CategoryID])
);
```

Here's my method:

```
public void AddRestaurant(string name, string addr, string city, string state, string zip, int category)
{
    DBConnect objDB = new DBConnect();

    objCmd.Parameters.Clear();
    objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    objCmd.CommandText = "AddRestaurant";

    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theName", name);
    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theAddr", addr);
    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theCity", city);
    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theState", state);
    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theZip", zip);
    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theCategory", category);

    objDB.GetConnection().Open();
    objDB.DoUpdateUsingCmdObj(objCmd);
    int affectedRows = objDB.DoUpdateUsingCmdObj(objCmd);
    objDB.CloseConnection();
}
```

Here's the click event in the aspx.cs file:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        rest.RestName = txtRestName.Text;
        rest.RestAddr = txtRestAddr.Text;
        rest.RestCity = txtRestCity.Text;
        rest.RestState = ddStates.SelectedValue;
        rest.RestZip = txtRestZip.Text;
        rest.CategoryID = int.Parse(ddCategories.SelectedValue);

        p.AddRestaurant(txtRestName.Text, txtRestAddr.Text, txtRestCity.Text, ddStates.SelectedItem.Value, txtRestZip.Text, int.Parse(ddCategories.SelectedValue));

        string error = txtRestName.Text + " has been added!";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + error + "');", true);
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        string error = txtRestName.Text + " has NOT been added!" + ex;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + error + "');", true);
    }
}
```

Here's my aspx page :

```
<fieldset class="center, content2">
            <legend>Restaurant Info</legend>
            <asp:Label ID="lblRestName" runat="server" CssClass="left">Name: </asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRestName" runat="server" CssClass="right"></asp:TextBox>
            <br /><br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblRestAddr" runat="server" CssClass="left">Address: </asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRestAddr" runat="server" CssClass="right"></asp:TextBox>
            <br /><br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblRestCity" runat="server" CssClass="left">City: </asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRestCity" runat="server" CssClass="right"></asp:TextBox>
            <br /><br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblRestState" runat="server" CssClass="left">State: </asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddStates" runat="server" CssClass="right" Width="140px">
                <asp:ListItem Value="AL">Alabama</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="AK">Alaska</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="AZ">Arizona</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="AR">Arkansas</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="CA">California</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="CO">Colorado</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="CT">Connecticut</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="DC">District of Columbia</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="DE">Delaware</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="FL">Florida</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="GA">Georgia</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="HI">Hawaii</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="ID">Idaho</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="IL">Illinois</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="IN">Indiana</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="IA">Iowa</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="KS">Kansas</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="KY">Kentucky</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="LA">Louisiana</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="ME">Maine</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="MD">Maryland</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="MA">Massachusetts</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="MI">Michigan</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="MN">Minnesota</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="MS">Mississippi</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="MO">Missouri</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="MT">Montana</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="NE">Nebraska</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="NV">Nevada</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="NH">New Hampshire</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="NJ">New Jersey</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="NM">New Mexico</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="NY">New York</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="NC">North Carolina</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="ND">North Dakota</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="OH">Ohio</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="OK">Oklahoma</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="OR">Oregon</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="PA">Pennsylvania</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="RI">Rhode Island</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="SC">South Carolina</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="SD">South Dakota</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="TN">Tennessee</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="TX">Texas</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="UT">Utah</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="VT">Vermont</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="VA">Virginia</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="WA">Washington</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="WV">West Virginia</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="WI">Wisconsin</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="WY">Wyoming</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br /><br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblRestZip" runat="server" CssClass="left">Zip Code: </asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRestZip" runat="server" CssClass="right"></asp:TextBox>
            <br /><br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblCategory" runat="server" CssClass="left">Category: </asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddCategories" runat="server" CssClass="right" Width="140px">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">American</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Mexican</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">Korean</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4">Chinese</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5">Japanese</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" CssClass="button2" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnReview" Text="Add Review" runat="server" OnClick="btnReview_Click" CssClass="button2" />
        </fieldset>
```

Comment: Are you sure about what database are you checking? It is the same database defined in your connectionstring? Could you post this connectionstring?

Comment: You are inserting your data twice.

Comment: I don't see the code that's actually executing the procedure. It looks like some sort of wrapper. I see it referenced in a few places on websites. But there's no way of knowing whether your procedure is actually getting executed. My guess is it's not. You might want to try this the old fashioned way, creating a `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, and executing it. That wrapper probably isn't adding anything of value except making it harder for you to tell what's actually happening.

Comment: @Steve it is quite long but I am sure it is used correctly.  https://gist.github.com/76342ck/6333cc69ac82bd9c81ab4e7567c0fc05

Comment: Your DoUpdateUsingCmdObj returns an integer. What is the value returned by the call? Is it zero or is it one? Notice also that handling an exception in the way you do inside the DoUpdateUsingCmdObj is a bad practice. Discarding the error without any kind of logging will make your work harder.

Comment: @Steve I only added that so that I can use the debugger in visual studio 2017 as a breakpoint so that I could figure out what was going wrong.

Comment: Again, what is the value returned in the affectedrows? If it is 1 then your code is working and adding the record but not in the database that your are looking at. Did you use the Server Explorer windows inside Visual Studio? Are the connectionstring there the same?

Comment: @ScottHannen the old fashioned way worked. I will play around it more to see why my way won't.

Comment: It's an odd phenomenon that developers create little wrapper classes for SQL commands. 95% of the time it doesn't add any value, and you end up having to read the wrapper code to make sure it's doing what you expect, and meanwhile it's just as easy use the `System.Data.SqlClient` classes directly.

Comment: Dan Guzman says: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - please read the article and stop using it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error. I was opening my connection twice.

```
objDB.GetConnection().Open();
```

Change it to:

```
objDB.GetConnection();
```

Comment: And you also appear to **execute** your stored procedure twice:  `objDB.DoUpdateUsingCmdObj(objCmd);  
    int affectedRows = objDB.DoUpdateUsingCmdObj(objCmd);` that might lead to duplicate rows being inserted